# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PersistentBottomSheetController<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, dart-null-safety

I am now converting my codes into null safety. So now I have done this changes to my codes. Initially the return type was void then I have change into Future? but yet I do get the the error on this `Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PersistentBottomSheetController<dynamic>' in type cast`. What are the other changes I can do to fix it.

```
Future<dynamic>? _showBottomSheet(
      context, MapDashboardDetails details) async {
   
    //_showPersBottomSheetCallBack = null;
    showingBottomSheet = true;

    _controller = _scaffoldKey.currentState!
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
          return VBottomSheet(
            details: details,            
            onCloseTapped: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          );
        })
        .closed
        .whenComplete(() {
          if (mounted) {
            showingBottomSheet = false;
            _showPersBottomSheetCallBack = _showBottomSheet;
          }
        }) as PersistentBottomSheetController;
    return null;
  }
```

Here is how I am calling it. Even this was before void and then I added the  Future and async but yet not able to resolve it.

```
Future<dynamic> _onMarkerTapped(MapDashboardDetails details) async {
  
    if (showingBottomSheet) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      showingBottomSheet = false;
    }   
    _showBottomSheet(context, details);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState!
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
        ...
        })
        .closed
        .whenComplete(() {
          ...
        });
```

this returns a Future and not a PersistentBottomSheetController.
Therefor your cast(= as ...) tries to cast a Future<void> to something which it is not. So the solution is to just return the future that `whenComplete` return
:

```
return _scaffoldKey.currentState!
        .showBottomSheet((context) {
        ...
        })
        .closed
        .whenComplete(() {
          ...
        });
```

Comment: it seems to be working but I dont get a bit on the logic where you said to remove the casting as PersistentBottomSheetController;. Actually in case so the return is Future<dynamic> is it correct to change that from void ?

Comment: whenComplete give you a Future<void> which is basically a Future without any data returned. This is only done so you can await the process. Sadly I'm not 100% familiar with `showBottomSheet` but I can image you could add methods before or after `close` which can handle returned data.

Comment: looked it up and if you write `showBottomSheet<TYPE>` it will return a `Future<TYPE>`. So you could change it to that if you actually return something

Comment: no issue it seems to be working but I just wanted to know the logic of its working so that I am clearer on the exact issue

Comment: I dont really write anything like this showBottomSheet<TYPE> ?